# Как применить цикл к программе и остановить ее одним символом?

Tags: java, while, switch, scanner

Как сделать, чтобы программа запрашивала ввод номера месяца до тех пор, пока пользователь не введёт символ `q`?

И как применить цикл в данной программе?

```
package com.it.app;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lesson2ClassWork1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Введите номер месяца");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = sc.nextInt();

    switch (x) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("January");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("February");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("March");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("April");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("May");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("June");
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("July");
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("August");
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("September");
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("October");
        break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println("November");
        break;
    case 12:
        System.out.println("December");
        break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Неверное значение. Введите номер от 1 до 
12");
}

}

}
```

Comment: Вам уже училка циклы рассказывала?

Comment: А про массивы никто из училок не знает?

Answer (score 1):

Не надо изобретать велосипед. Все методы вам предоставлены. И не нужно никакие эксепшыны хандлить.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    int x;

    do {
        System.out.println("Введите номер месяца");
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            x = sc.nextInt();

            switch (x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("January");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("February");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("March");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("April");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("May");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("June");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("July");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("August");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("September");
                break;
            case 10:
                System.out.println("October");
                break;
            case 11:
                System.out.println("November");
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println("December");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Неверное значение. Введите номер от 1 до 12");
            }
        }
        input = sc.nextLine();
    } while (!input.equals("q"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно упростить код с использованием перечислением `Mount` из пакета `java.time`. Плюс такого способа в том, что можно ставить `TextStyle`, `Locale`, а главное не надо создавать большую [switch](/questions/tagged/switch) конструкцию.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int x;

do {
   System.out.println("Введите номер месяца: ");
   x = scan.nextInt();
   if(x == -1) break;

   Month mount = Month.of(x);
   System.out.println(mount.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));

}while (x != -1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Как то так. Работает, но надо доработать. Просто немного переделал Ваш код:

```
public class Lesson2ClassWork1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException{

    getMonth();
}

static void getMonth()throws NumberFormatException {
    System.out.println("Введите номер месяца");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str = sc.next();
    try {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(str);

        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("January");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("February");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("March");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("April");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("May");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("June");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("July");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("August");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("September");
                break;
            case 10:
                System.out.println("October");
                break;
            case 11:
                System.out.println("November");
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println("December");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Неверное значение. Введите номер от 1 до 12");

        }
    }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        if (str.equals("q")) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            getMonth();
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, нужно в цикле спрашивать номер пока не будет введено 'q'